# Why does integration for parametric equations work here?

Tags: calculus

Consider $x=\sin t, y=\cos t,t\in[0,\pi]$, which traces out this semicircle:
[image]

I want to find the area of this semicircle.

The definite integral is supposed to give me the signed area. So, it seems to me that we should have $$\int^1_0 y \ dx=0?$$

(The top right quadrant has positive area $\pi/4$, while the bottom right has negative area $-\pi/4$, so these should cancel out and give us $0$.)

Yet if we proceed as usual with substitution, we get the correct answer:

$$\int^1_0 y \ dx= \int^\pi_0 y \frac{dx}{dt} dt=\int^\pi_0 \cos^2 t \ dt=[\frac{t}{2}+\frac{\sin 2t}{2}]^\pi_0=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Why is this? (Or where have I gone wrong in my above reasoning?)

Comment: It should be obvious that the area of the semicircle _can't_ be zero. Hence your reasoning in that case is where the issue lies.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, your limits are incorrect. If you are integrating between $x=0$ and $x=1$ then the corresponding $t$ values are from $t=0$ to $t=\frac \pi 2$. Using these limits will give the answer of $\frac \pi 4$, which is the area above the $x$-axis.

If you want the area below the $x$-axis then the corresponding $t$ values are from $\frac \pi 2$ to $\pi$. Using these limits will give the answer of $-\frac \pi 4$, which is the area above the $x$-axis.

Normally, the definite integral is the signed area between the curve $y$ and the $x$-axis when $y$ has a single well-defined value. In the graph you have drawn, there are two values of $y$ for each value of $x$, so which one do you mean?

Comment: So why does my definite integral arrive at the correct answer $\pi/2$? Was it just luck? Or is there some reason why my blind and mistaken manipulations arrive at the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

The notion in which the integral gives the “signed area” is strictly intended for the area between a function and the      x-axis, your semicircle is not a function, so that rule isn’t very relevant, the sense in which it would be zero is if you added the two functions that give the two different y values as a function of $x$, so you would only be integrating 0. The reason  why your parametric version gives the correct answer for the area of the semicircle is because in the integral from 0 to $\frac \pi 2$ you find the area of the top quadrant, integrating $ydx$. From $\frac \pi 2$ to $\pi$, the integral is covering the bottom quadrant, while it would seem that since y is negative, the integral here should’ve negative because y is negative, it is important to recognize that dx is also negative since we’re moving to the left, so the negatives cancel out when we multiply.